# Select/Deselect Button Showing

Tags: web-part

In my original list, there was a column for select/deselect.  I changed the properties so it does not show up.

In the associated web parts page showing this list, the select/deselect button still shows up.  How do I get rid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List views in web parts are not dynamic. If you set a view in a web part based on an existing view and then edit the view, the web part does not update as changes are made to the view, they become static based on how the view was defined at that time.

You must go into the web part and change the view to something different, Apply, switch back, and Apply, or click the link to Change this View and remove the unnecessary column to match your view.

This has been the behavior for a long while.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the web part and set the view again.

Comment: I went to the web part ( far right side) and also tried to uncheck the asynchronous update.  I then went to the original list, hit modify, and OK

Comment: Async update determines how the data is filled into the web part, it has nothing to do with updating the view.

Comment: If the list is showing correct, then is it how the web part is updating.

Comment: Greg, my understanding is that web part is working based on a view of the list. In such case, the web part stores its own version of the view which doesn't change when you change the original view. You can update the web part and set the view again and save the web part.

Comment: Just observed that Eric has provided step by step instructions for the solution i suggested. I come across this often in our projects.

Comment: Sorry for the newbie questions but how do I set the view again?

Comment: Edit the page and edit the web part. You will see the drop down with the views of the related list. You can change it to something else save and edit again to bring it back to the original view. (just a false update! so as to apply the same view again). save the web part and page. http://www.ucdenver.edu/about/departments/WebServices/sharepoint/onlineTraining/more/webparts/Pages/listviewwebpart.aspx

Comment: I get cannot sav all of the property settings as file is not checked out. Is the checkout on the original list file?

Comment: I changed it to a different view and then the columns changed to that view.   However the select/deselect buttton was still there.  I changed columns back to the view I wanted.